# What does it mean when pygame is initialized?

Tags: python, pygame

The Pygame documentation says that `pygame.init()` Initializes all `pygame` modules which need to be initialized. What does it mean to initialize a Pygame module in Python.

I understand that `pygame.init()` *'starts everything up'* but what is it meant by 'starts everything up'?

Comment: What exactly is unclear about the term "initialize" or "start"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.init()` does indeed initiate all Pygame modules. They don't come initiated or "started" when you import Pygame because starting every module when you import Pygame can make your code slow. By having to use `pygame.init()`, your code will only run Pygame modules if you want it to.
You can also start specific modules in Pygame. `pygame.mixer.init()` for example, only starts the mixer module in Pygame and not everything else.

Note that this is a Pygame feature, and `.init()` is not for every module in Python. Some Pygame source code is run when you call `pygame.init()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general definition of "initializing a module" in Python, but initializing a Pygame module means preparing it for use by allocating resources and configuring essential settings. The `pygame.init()` function sets up the display system, sound system, input devices, and other crucial components needed for game development.

"Starting everything up" refers to the actions performed during initialization. It involves configuring the display mode, setting up the sound system, initializing input devices, and preparing other modules like image processing and networking.

You can refer to the [source code](https://github.com/myint/pygame/blob/master/src/base.c#L255) if you are interested in details. It's in C (not Python) but is relatively easy to read.